# Stretched texture when UV mapping

Tags: uv

I stumbled onto a strange stretch while unwrapping UVs. I'm curious what could be causing this:

[image]

For general information:

- I've applied the scale, so this is a 1,1,1 scale object
- I am feeding in the UVs thru the shader editor
- I've applied the material
- I've tried marking the seam around the faces facing the camera and that seemed to fix it, but I'm not sure if that's the correct fix for this.

I don't know what exactly is going on here, the other questions I've looked through seemed to be a different issue.

Comment: You are seeing texture distortion.  In particular, you're seeing triangulation artifacts arising from distortion.  Unwrapping with more seams is indeed the way to reduce distortion.  Using more vertices, incl. via procedural subdivision, can also be used to reduce how noticeable the triangulation artifacts are.

Comment: In this case. Re-Unwrapping seemed to fix for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTbmi.png

Comment: thanks all, re-unwrapping didn't fix it for me. however, adding an extra seam on those particular faces did the trick. will prolly settle for this: 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opOqq.png